# Why doesn't my SSH key work with Google Cloud Source repositories?

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-source-repos

I've done this with github, gitlab and other repos... But I am trying to set an ssh key with cloud source repositories

```
git clone ssh://<user_name>@<domain>.com@source.developers.google.com:2022/p/<project-id>/r/omni-orchestrator
```

and it is giving me a :

```
Cloning into 'omni-orchestrator'...
Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address '[<Some_IP>]:2022' to the list of known hosts.
<user_name>@<domain>.com@source.developers.google.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I am able to clone via `gcloud`, so I have the required permissions to acces the repo... just not with ssh.

```bash
$ gcloud source repos clone omni-orchestrator --project=<project_id>
Cloning into '/home/<user>/workspaces/<client>/gcp/omni-orchestrator'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
Project [<project_id>] repository [omni-orchestrator] was cloned to [/home/<user>/workspaces/<client>/gcp/omni-orchestrator].
```

I created several keys using [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/authentication#linux-or-macos), and changing the key name.

Also, here are a few attempts I made according to a few similar posts and some helpful advice.

Create `config` file in `~/.ssh` to specify the used private key

```
Host gitserv
    Hostname source.developers.google.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<user_name>_<domain>_com
    User <user_name>@<domain>.com
```

Set variable :`GIT_SSH_COMMAND`

```
<user_name>@AWESOME-<user_name>3:~/workspaces/<domain>/gcp$ export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -v -i /home/<user_name>/.ssh/<user_name>_<domain>_com -o IdentitiesOnly=yes'
<user_name>@AWESOME-<user_name>3:~/workspaces/<domain>/gcp$ git clone ssh://<user_name>@<domain>.com@source.developers.google.com:2022/p/<project_id>/r/omni-orchestrator
fatal: destination path 'omni-orchestrator' already exists and is not an empty directory.
<user_name>@AWESOME-<user_name>3:~/workspaces/<domain>/gcp$ cd ..
<user_name>@AWESOME-<user_name>3:~/workspaces/<domain>$ git clone ssh://<user_name>@<domain>.com@source.developers.google.com:2022/p/<project_id>/r/omni-orchestrator
Cloning into 'omni-orchestrator'...
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.7, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/<user_name>/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to source.developers.google.com [74.125.133.82] port 2022.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/<user_name>/.ssh/<user_name>_<domain>_com type 2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<user_name>/.ssh/<user_name>_<domain>_com-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Go
debug1: no match: Go
debug1: Authenticating to source.developers.google.com:2022 as '<user_name>@<domain>.com'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:AGvEpqYNMqsRNIviwyk4J4HM0lEylomDBKOWZsBn434
debug1: Host '[source.developers.google.com]:2022' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/<user_name>/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: ECDSA SHA256:z7IqQohzIjyZVpxTTGKams9JxhquHb9pYhtnWMfgkuE /home/<user_name>/.ssh/<user_name>_<domain>_com
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
<user_name>@<domain>.com@source.developers.google.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 0):

From [gcloud Clone using SSH](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/cloning-repositories#gcloud), the "user" is supposed to be the *email*

```
git clone ssh://[EMAIL]@source.developers.google.com:2022/p/[PROJECT_ID]/r/[REPO_NAME]
```

You did you the email in your `~/.ssh/config`, but you never used your config Host entry '`gitserv`'.
And said entry is missing a `Port 2022` in it.

Instead you defined a `GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -v -i ...`

The URL should be instead:

```
git clone gitserv:p/<project_id>/r/omni-orchestrator
```

If that still fails, then check the pre-requisites:

1. make sure [your key is registered](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/authentication#register_a_public_key)
2. You must have a [repository in Cloud Source Repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/creating-an-empty-repository).
3. You must have [permissions to interact with the repository](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/configure-access-control).
4. The repository to be cloned cannot have a restricted name such as `All-Users` or `All-Projects`.

Point 1. and 3. are relevant in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was to add a file named `config` (no file extension, i.e. no `.txt` extension) in my OpenSSH directory (on Windows it should be in `C:\Users\myusername\.ssh`) with the following:

```
Host source.developers.google.com
    HostName source.developers.google.com
    User myemail@mydomain.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-private-key-file
```